# For some questions edit option disabled on mobile website, Why?

Tags: support, edits

I don't see edit option for some questions like on below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152545/java-printing-3-intergers-using-scanner-class

What is the problem here ?

Is it purposely disabled or some bug, I am not sure.

Please anyone know about this.

I am using mobile website of SO on my Lumia 820.

Comment: Now I am able to see, Is this right behaviour?

Comment: That post was edited by a user with <2k rep and the edit was therefore reviewed. Until the review is complete, other users can't suggest edits.

Comment: [Why is the edit button disabled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled)